# Python sorted list containing all integers in both consumed list

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion

How would I go about writing a recursive function that consumes two lists and then produces a list with the elements that are in both lists? If both lists have a number twice in each, the produced list will also have that number in it twice.
This is what I have so far:

`def merge(L1, L2, i, j, R):
        if L1[i] == L2[j]:
                R.append(L1[i])
                R.append(L2[j])
                merge(L1, L2, i, j+1, R)
        else:
                merge(L1, L2, i+1, j, R)

def sorted_intersection(lst1, lst2):
        R = []
        return merge(lst1, lst2, lst1[0], lst2[0], R)`

Nvm, figured out the code. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you please post an example of what you have tried and an expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "consumes two lists"? It's easy to have a function like this: `def consume(list1, list2): return list1 + list2`. Whether you consider list1 and list2 having been consumed, I don't know.

Comment: There are two rules about recursion in Python: 1. You use recursion only if there is no other way. 2. There always is an other way.

Comment: I added my work so far

Answer (score 1):

Please see the documentation of the module [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), which contains helpers for many functional tasks:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

# Preserves the order of b:
def in_both(a, b):
    # Count the occurrences of elements in a:
    a = Counter(a)
    # Default to 0:
    a = defaultdict(lambda: 0, a)

    # Return true if there is a positive amount of items x in a left:
    def take_from_a(x):
        cur = a[x]
        if cur > 0:
            a[x] = cur - 1
            return True

    # Filter out elements in b that are not often enough in b:
    return filter(take_from_a, b)

in_both("abbcccdddd", "abcdabcde") == "abcdbcd"
```

In here `a` and `b` are both iterated once.

Answer (score 0):

Why recursive?

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3] 
b = [2, 3, 4] 

result = [[x, b.remove(x)][0] for x in a if x in b] 
result
[2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I will be tested on my ability to write these types of python functions recursively and without replace or find